# What effect does radioactive material have on the structure of spacetime?

Tags: spacetime, radioactivity

I am curious as to how nuclear energy, from a nuclear blast could effect the structure of spacetime if the radiation escaped the atmosphere. Would it weaken the structure or would it be harmless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spacetime does not have a "strength" like a material, and thus it cannot be "weakened". I believe your problem is you're taking that problematic "rubber sheet" analogy - where the effect by which curved spacetime caused by a heavy, gravitating object produces gravity is likened to how that a ball rolls into the depression on a depressed rubber sheet produced by a heavy object resting upon it. And this is not a very good analogy for a number of reasons, and you've hit upon one of its limitations in this post. It should only be considered as a very, very rough proxy.

What "warped spacetime" *really* means is the *laws of geometry* are different and, moreover, fluid, in that they can vary from point to point in space and moment to moment in time. Such laws include things like the angle sum of a triangle, which lines are parallel to another line, and so forth, but more fundamentally include the *distance* between points and the *angle* between lines. The presence of matter causes these to deviate from their usual definitions. And geometry doesn't have a "strength", so to talk about that is nonsensical.

Nonetheless, you can ask what effect a nuclear explosion has on space-time geometry and the answer is "very little". If anything, it causes a *relaxation* of the geometry in the following sense. Consider a nuclear bomb free-floating in the vacuum of intergalactic space, far from all other matter. When the bomb is together, all its matter *and energy* - *both* of which contribute to gravity given Einstein's famous $E = mc^2$ - are concentrated in one small area of space. Thus their gravitational field will be relatively strong close by. If you want the rubber sheet, it makes a deep dimple in an otherwise flat region (due to the lack of other matter). (But you can even get this from Newton's law of gravity in this case, you don't need general relativity to describe the gravitational field!)

When the bomb explodes, it *scatters* both its matter and energy very rapidly (radiation goes out at the speed of light, matter goes out at 1000 km/s or more). After a short time, it is spread so thinly that we again, effectively, have a vacuum, and thus the geometry is approximately flat again as there is no highly concentrated matter/energy to cause a strong local distortion. The explosion does not *increase* the distortion, it does exactly the opposite: it *decreases* it, because the energy that was released was already there and already warping spacetime as much as it ever would before the bomb even detonated, it just got converted to other forms. And it doesn't matter how big the bomb is: the principle will apply regardless. Everything spreads out, nothing gets more concentrated. The energy and matter is as concentrated as it will *ever* be *before* you press the detonate button. All that happens is some of that energy changes forms, which allow it to begin spreading outward instead of remaining collected together in a single place.

And thus we *also* can see what we'd have to do *to* create an increase in the distortion of space-time, and that is we would need in fact the exact *OPPOSITE* of an explosion: an *im* -plosion. And this is how that things like neutron stars and black holes are created - a heavy star uses up its fusion fuel and stops producing heat to keep itself inflated against its own gravity, and then implodes, collapsing inward. As it does so its mass concentrates and the distortion of spacetime nearby it goes up. If it is massive enough, it collapses beyond a point of no return: the "Schwarzschild radius", at which point a boundary called an event horizon, where nothing can move away from the object, forms. This is, of course, what we call a black hole. What happens to it after this is unknown: general relativity theory predicts it collapses to zero size and then ceases to exist, but we know this makes no sense because the disappearance of the energy its matter contains like that is a blatant violation of the first law of thermodynamics - in effect, a perpetual motion machine, but in the opposite sense: a device that destroys energy into nothing instead of creating it out of nothing. Thus some new kind of theory is required here - though it seems that the collapse at least up to the point of the horizon formation is quite likely to be real, esp. given the recent observations from LIGO. Understanding the rest and - in particular, whether or not that perhaps maybe a black hoel *does* "tear" or "rupture" the fabric of space-time in some fashion and that maybe your intuition was not quite so wrong after all - is in fact something we do not have, but only have speculative theories. In particular, to answer it likely will require the involvement of quantum mechanics, and its combination with general relativity is not straightforward. While there are many theories that purport to do this, there is no way to get any experimental support for any of them using existing technology and understandings.

But insofar as making a black hole with a bomb is concerned, you can't, because as said a bomb is as concentrated as it will ever be *before* it detonates, *unless* you were using the bombs in such a way as to create a powerful *im* -plosion, i.e. as compressors, with numerous bombs all surrounding a single piece of target matter and exploding so as to crush it inward. This would require, however, bombs a lot worse than anything we *can* build given our existing technology, if it is possible at all. But that's beside the point: were it capable of producing enough energy on *ex* -plosion to form a black hole, i.e. instead of *im* -ploding, it'd already be one!